# User defined function only returns NULL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this following MySQL code:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION durationInMinutes(id INT)
RETURNS INT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
   DECLARE Minutes INT;
   SET Minutes =
      (SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(timeDeparture, timeArrival)) FROM AirRoute
       WHERE pk_id = id) / 60;
   RETURN Minutes;
END$$
DELIMITER;
```

Basically, this function calculates the duration of a flight in minutes. The parameter is the id of the flight. For some reason though, this function always returns NULL. I even checked this:

```
SELECT (SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(timeDeparture, timeArrival)) FROM AirRoute
       WHERE pk_id = 925) / 60;
```

This does return the correct answer if I put id = 925, so there could be something wrong with the RETURN statement.

Comment: How about `SELECT .. INTO Minutes ...` ?

Comment: It sounds as if you want it to return something when you DON'T give it a pk_id.  In order to do this, you have to change "WHERE pk_id = " to "WHERE pk_id = coalesce(input_id, pk_id)".  One more thing, it's always a good practice to alias the input paramter to avoid confusion.  So, parameter id should be something like "search_id".  Also, you are going to get fractional minutes in your result set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect there is a column called `id` in the table.  I *always* name parameters and local variables in a way to distinguish them from column names:

```
CREATE FUNCTION durationInMinutes (
    in_id INT
)
RETURNS INT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
   DECLARE out_Minutes INT;

   SELECT out_Minutes := TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(timeDeparture, timeArrival))
   FROM AirRoute ar
   WHERE ar.pk_id = in_id) / 60;

   RETURN out_Minutes;
END$$
```

Comment: No, there isn't. I even checked beforehand. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved it. This is my corrected code:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION durationInMinutes(id INT)
RETURNS INT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
   RETURN (SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(timeDeparture, timeArrival))
           FROM AirRoute
           WHERE pk_id = id / 60);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Still, I really don't understand why it wasn't possible using a temp variable.